# Angular use ng-content class not apply

Tags: angular, styles, ng-content

I have an application in which I have a layout. In this layout I have a div with 2 ng-content. My problem is that my classes do not apply

```
<div class="col-12 pr-1 pl-0 row m-0 p-0">
    <ng-content class="col-6 mr-0 pr-3 pl-0" select=".content-last-name"></ng-content>
    <ng-content class="col-6 m-0 p-0" select=".content-first-name"></ng-content>
</div>
```

What is the problem

Comment: Please, share your code or more explain.

Comment: @dna Please provide a sample code and where is you problem. Please let us know.

Comment: @dna yeah, it will be great if we have the code, make sure your component is declared on the app.module and that you have all the selectors etc....

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

`ng-content` tags won't actually be rendered in the DOM, they are just angular specific syntax. So the classes you add there are just "lost". As a workaround you can surround both your `ng-content` tags with another tag, and add classes to them.

```
<div class="col-12 pr-1 pl-0 row m-0 p-0">
    <section class="col-6 mr-0 pr-3 pl-0">
        <ng-content select=".content-last-name"></ng-content>
    </section>
    <section class="col-6 m-0 p-0">
        <ng-content select=".content-first-name"></ng-content>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. It doesn’t take it into account

Comment: My fields do not take up all the width available whereas if I don’t put them in an ng-content, it works without problem

Comment: What is the solution please